# Can you load a dataset into Stata and keep regression estimates from a previous dataset stored?

Tags: regression, multiple-regression, stata

I have a panel regression model that I am running on 6 datasets comprised of crop yields for 6 different crops. I have run multiple specifications for each crop working towards an ideal specification. I want to generate a table using    `esttab` that uses the final regression from each dataset, however, whenever I try to import a dataset with one in memory, i get an error message as Stata will not be "destructive" unless specifically told to do so.

In short, how do I keep results from one dataset and then be able to clear and load another without losing it? I am using the `estimates store` command for the results

Comment: Maybe best to find a way to keep six different datasets separate. It it's like Minitab, save the session along with the first dataset (as if it's too late to finish and you're afraid one of those surprise software 'upgrades' will destroy your work overnight). Then start a fresh session for the second dataset. Minitab allows multiple datasets to be open and you can switch among them, but I never trust that (or my memory of which is which). // Voting to close. IMHO, this is about details of using Stata, not about statistics.

Comment: I will be happy to answer this question if you post it on Stack Overflow with a reproducible example using one of Stata's toy datasets. See the Stata tag wiki there for advice.

Comment: I already figured a work around for it. Stata 16 includes multiple dataset capabilities whereas Stata 15, my version, does not. I did a rather gross way by combining two datasets but using y1 and y2 for the same variable but two datasets and just using different variables in the regression.